# Python/PIL изменить размер изображений в папке

Tags: python, pil

Задача: изменить размер всех *.png в папке

Один из файлов до: `xiaomi_200x100.width-200.png   4830 bytes`

```
In [11]:                                             
    ...: from PIL import Image                                              
    ...: import os, sys                       
    ...:                                                
    ...: path = "/var/www/gglobal/media/images/"        
    ...: dirs = os.listdir( path )                                       
    ...:         
    ...: def resize():
    ...:     for item in dirs:
    ...:         if os.path.isfile(path+item):
    ...:             im = Image.open(path+item)
    ...:             f, e = os.path.splitext(path+item)
    ...:             imResize = im.resize((200,100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    ...:             imResize.save(f, 'png', quality=80)
    ...: 
    ...: resize()
```

и после : `xiaomi_200x100.width-200.png   4830 bytes`

Сперва думал, что не правильно смотрю размер:

```
In [11]: import os                                                          
    ...: for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/var/www/gglobal/media/images/'):
    ...:     for fn in files:                 
    ...:         path = os.path.join(root, fn)          
    ...:         size = os.stat(path).st_size           
    ...:         print('{}   {} bytes'.format(path.split('/')[-1], size))
```

но он действительно не меняется, но ошибок никаких нету ...

Что не так?

Comment: А вы не опечатались в пути `path`, может там должно быть `/var/www/global/media/images` и ваш скрипт просто не заходит в цикл. Как вариант добавьте в цикл `print` с выводом названия обрабатываемого изображения.

Answer (score 3):

Я использую вот такую функцию:

```
def resize(filename):
    img = Image.open(os.path.join(FOLDER, filename))
    img.thumbnail((1000, 1000), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img.save(os.path.join(FOLDER + 'p1000x1000', filename))
    return 'ok'
```

Где `FOLDER` - путь, директория с файлом и в ней директория с новыми, измененными файлами